# Pyplot Stacked histogram - amount of occurences in column

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram, stacked

I'm trying to present datatable collected from firewall logs in a histogram so that i would have one bar for each date in the file, and the number of occurences in a certain column stacked in the bar.

I looked into several examples here but they all seemed to be based on the fact that i would know what values there are in the particular column - and what i'm trying to achieve here is the way to present histogram without needing to know all possible fields.

In the example i have used protocol as the column:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

csvs = glob.glob("*log-export.csv")
dfs = [pd.read_csv(csv, sep="\xff", engine="python") for csv in csvs]

df_merged = pd.concat(dfs).fillna("")

data = df_merged[['date', 'proto']]
np_data = np.array(data)

plt.hist(np_data, stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

But this shows following diagram:

[histogram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfGkA.png)

and i would like to accomplish something like this:

[stacked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJKXb.png)

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Comment: You should fill one histogram (of the protocol) per date (or the other way round), then plot them like [here](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/bar_stacked.html).
Currently you fill one histogram with dates and protocols, which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**
I had to make up data because you didn't provide any.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    Date=pd.date_range(end=pd.to_datetime('now'), periods=100, freq='H'),
    Proto=np.random.choice('UDP TCP ICMP'.split(), 100, p=(.3, .5, .2))
))
```

---

**Solution**
Use `pd.crosstab` then plot

```
pd.crosstab(df.Date.dt.date, df.Proto).plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for - thank you!